# "Can't start git: git.exe" warning pop-up message in PyCharm 5.0.2

Tags: git, version-control, pycharm

Any idea how to permanently suppress this (regularly appearing) PyCharm 5.0.2 warning message, since I'm using Atlassian SourceTree 1.5.23.0 VCS with BitBucket (instead of PyCharm VCS add-in for BitBucket). OS: Windows 7, SP1.
[image]

If I specify where git.exe is located, then PyCharm wants to rule my VCS, but this isn't desireable.

Answer (score 8):

figured it out...
In Settings | Version Control: delete (unregister) project's root directory (select directory line and click "-" button).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot start Git: git.exe" below this message you can see "fix it" click on it it will ask for path you just go to the acttual path where you installed git for me its look like this **c:\Program Files\Git\cmd** choose that path it will work fine